# Appstore FailureNo architectures in the binary. Lipo failed to detect any architectures in the bundle executable.” At SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store

Hi I just tried to upload my app to the app store but it failed with error.

**

```
No architectures in the binary. Lipo failed to detect any
architectures in the bundle executable.
```

**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi I'm glad i found the Answer. The problem was actually with my 'Productname' in info.plist . It was different in my first version.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, how exactly did you solved it? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

That can also happen when the Cocoapods cache is not in sync, then just

```
pod install
```

solves the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Same thing. Had this issue. I just changed 
**Project -> Build Settings -> Produc Name**     (wrote:  "**Wundmanager**")

then

**Project -> General -> Identity -> Bundle Identifier** (wrote "**imeksbank.Wundmanager**")

my nick is imeksbank

and then

**iTunes Connect** and the same to Bundle-ID  (chnaged "**imeksbank.Wundmanager**")

After that it worked for me. I am also new and today is my first day i can Upload my first App.
xcode 5.1.1
ios 7.1

Answer (score 2):

Can also be caused by embedding a static framework (mistaking it for a dynamic one) in your app. Easily done if you build in different phases and/or allow xcode to "build implicit dependencies".

Answer (score 2):

After a long struggle with an error message like this, I finally understood that mistakenly an iOS framework had been copied into the IPA. This was added automatically following the usual steps to add a framework to an iOS project.

So the solution would be to remove "Embed Frameworks" phase from "Build Phases".

[image]

Comment: @NotBatman asks, *I'm confused. You're saying the IPA shouldn't have an embedded Framework. Right? If that's the case, than how do we use them? I'm using a pod installed to a custom Framework.*

Comment: For regular projects `pod` app should configure everything required correctly. In my example I had a framework written by myself. I just left it in "Linked Frameworks and Libraries".

Comment: But if I understand you correctly you had a pod inside of your framework? I didn't get that working for myself neither.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get past this error by restarting Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes cleaning your project quitting and re archiving will solve the issue. In my case it worked. I don't have any issues with the bundle name, identifier or plist.