# ERROR ITMS-90085 when uploading an archived app to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, itmstransporter

when archiving my app and trying to upload the binary to iTunes Connect through Xcode or Application Loader (after a successful export), I have this error without much more information:

```
ERROR ITMS-90085: "No architectures in the binary. Lipo failed to detect any architectures in the bundle executable."
```

More information:
- iOS app (min version: iOS 9.0)
- Xcode 7.3 (no update available in MAS)

Did you ever encounter this error? What is this about? How can I fix it?

EDIT: in my Info.plist, my product name didn't change between last version submission and now, so this answer ([Appstore FailureNo architectures in the binary. Lipo failed to detect any architectures in the bundle executable.” At SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412068/appstore-failureno-architectures-in-the-binary-lipo-failed-to-detect-any-archit)) doesn't work in this case.

Thanks,
Cyril

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Appstore FailureNo architectures in the binary. Lipo failed to detect any architectures in the bundle executable.” At SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412068/appstore-failureno-architectures-in-the-binary-lipo-failed-to-detect-any-archit)

Comment: in my Info.plist, my product name didn't change between last version submission and now, so this answer doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to upload my IPA to iTunes Connect after upgrading CocoaPods version, updating and reinstalling all pods.

I still don't know what happened.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem using Application Loader 3.0.  After I upgraded to XCode 8 and used the Application Loader bundled with it (3.6), my upload worked.

Answer (score 0):

Tryed two times by Fastlane and Xcode, the same error appeared, than i:

1. Cleaned project and *derived data*.
2. Removed everything from *Frameworks* folder (*Projectname* - *Frameworks* in project navigator)
3. Close and open *Xcode*.
4. `bundle update fastlane`
5. `bundle install` (updated cocoapods)
6. `pod update`

After this everything loads well by fastalane