# ERROR ITMS-90085: "No architectures in the binary. Lipo failed to detect any architectures in the bundle executable." Uploading Error

Tags: objective-c, firebase, lipo

I use relatedSDK for Firebase integration and while uploading App I encounter this error.

[image]

> ERROR ITMS-90085: "No architectures in the binary. Lipo failed to detect any architectures in the bundle executable." ERROR ITMS-90085: "No architectures in the binary. Lipo failed to detect any architectures in the bundle executable."

Comment: Did you find solution of problem, I am facing same issue

Comment: Same issue. and the error description gives no actual understanding

Answer (score 1):

It might be of the "Embedded Framework" build phase.

See my answer over here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48693391/140927